# Override Vuetify RTL for specific component/component tree

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js, right-to-left

We have started using [RTL](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/bidirectionality/) in Vuetify, it works great but there is a slight problem in the [slider](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/sliders/) component.
The problem is that we use this component as the slider for a video time, but even when viewing RTL languages, the video slider starts from the left (well, at least that's how it's managed in Israel which is our top RTL country).

[image]

I would love an option to bypass the rtl config for specific places in the application, I can't find a way in Vuetify docs. Anyone has a clue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slider uses `this.$vuetify.rtl` to determine the direction. However, `this.$vuetify` is a global object, where changing the rtl value will change it for the whole application.

But you can replace the object in the component instance. To do this, you need to access the component instance, which you can do through a template ref or using a directive:

```
Vue.directive(
  'vuetify-ltr', 
  (el, binding, vnode) => {
    const instance = vnode.componentInstance
    if (!instance.$vuetify) return
    instance.$vuetify = new Proxy(instance.$vuetify, {
      get(target, prop, receiver) {
        return prop === 'rtl' ? false : target[prop]
      },
    })
  }
)
```

This uses a Proxy to keep the other data from `$vuetify` bound to the original object. But since VSlider does not use any other values from `$vuetify`, you could also just override the whole thing.

With the directive, you can now switch the direction for individual Vuetify components:

```html
<v-slider
  v-vuetify-ltr
  ...
/>
```

Here it is in a snippet:

```js
Vue.directive(
  'vuetify-ltr', 
  (el, binding, vnode) => {
    const instance = vnode.componentInstance
    if(!instance.$vuetify) return
    instance.$vuetify = new Proxy(instance.$vuetify, {
      get(target, prop, receiver) {
        return prop === 'rtl' ? false : target[prop]
      },
    })
  }
)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify({
    rtl: true,
  }),
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-slider label="rlt"></v-slider>
      <v-slider label="ltr" v-vuetify-ltr></v-slider>
      <v-slider label="still rlt"></v-slider>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's amazing! I'm working on adding it to the code.  regarding the ref="ltrSlider", is there a reason why it's there?

Comment: Oh, that was from playing around, I used a template ref first before putting the code into a directive, and just forgot to remove the ref

Comment: Cool, took me a while to uncover why it didn't work for me, now it works perfect, thanks a lot!